# Apply cascade animation RecyclerView Items in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-viewholder

I want to do the next animation:

When I click on an item of my RecyclerView the items before disappear with a cascade animation.

For example: I Click on my item placed at position 10, then the items from 0 to 9 have to disappear applying a cascade swipe-left animation.

How can do it?

At this moment I tried to apply like this:

ViewHolder methods:

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            swipeAnimation(position);
        }
    });

    lstViewsHolder.add(holder.itemView);

    setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);



}

private void swipeAnimation(int position){
     int init = 0;

    while(init < position){

        lstViewsHolder.get(init).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.swipe_left));
        init++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is using a custom `ItemAnimator`. You should try to extend either `SimpleItemAnimator` or `DefaultItemAnimator` to apply your animation.

The `ItemAnimator`s respond to data events from the adapter, so you should include logic in your adapter that calls `notifyItemRemoved()`or `notifyItemRangeRemoved()` so that the proper animation is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should iterate over you're array and each time remove that item and then call notifyItemRemoved, you may want to delay each operation so that you're animation look smooth.

```
mResults.remove(position);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```